# Using Lync SDK 2013 in Visual Studio 2012 console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-office, lync, lync-2013

I am trying to build a console application which will listen on a port and as per the messages it receives, it will change Lync client availability and status. However, I cannot build the application it firstly gives unable to find System.Windows.Browser.dll and even if I explicitly reference it, it gives a version error. Is it that I cannot use Lync Sdk classes in a Console Application? If I can then from where can I download depreciated versions of dll's.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you targeting the correct .Net Framework? (.Net 4.0, I think.)

Comment: The application is targeting .Net Framework 4.5.